# i am making old school pong on tkinter, and i cant figure out how to make the paddle move

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
tk = Tk()
cv = Canvas(tk, width = 1000, height = 500)
cv.configure(bg = "black")
p1 = cv.create_rectangle(975, 200, 965, 300, fill = "white", outline = "white")
p2 = cv.create_rectangle(25, 200, 35, 300, fill = "white", outline = "white")
ball = cv.create_rectangle(495, 245, 505, 255, fill = "white", outline = "white")
directionx = [13, -13]
directiony = [13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, 
-10, -11, -12, -13]
dx = (directionx[random.randint(0,len(directionx)-1)])
dy = (directiony[random.randint(0,len(directiony)-1)])
cv.pack()
def p1up():
    p1.y = -15
def p1down():
    p1.y = 15
cv.bind_all('<Key-Press-w>', p1.y + 15)
while True:
    cv.move(ball, dx, dy)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.016666)
```

i just want to move the p1 paddle with the w key. i have tried all sorts of configurations for the keybinding, but it doesnt seem to work, either i get an error, or the paddle just doesnt move

Comment: you are updating neither `dx` nor `dy`, you just set their values once at start and that's it, also `p1` doesn't have attribute `y` so you can't do `p1.y`, I suggest you look at some `pygame` tutorials as `pygame` is meant for games and those tutorials cover these basics (especially since you are not even using `mainloop` but your own custom loop (which btw you shouldn't do either, you should use `mainloop`)) and don't use `*` when importing

Comment: You can find tips about writing questions in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, for instance, your title is way too long and should be the first sentence in the body of the question, not the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
tk = Tk()
cv = Canvas(tk, width = 1000, height = 500)
cv.configure(bg = "black")
p1 = cv.create_rectangle(975, 200, 965, 300, fill = "white", outline = "white")
p2 = cv.create_rectangle(25, 200, 35, 300, fill = "white", outline = "white")
ball = cv.create_rectangle(495, 245, 505, 255, fill = "white", outline = "white")
directionx = [13, -13]
directiony = [13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9,
-10, -11, -12, -13]
dx = (directionx[random.randint(0,len(directionx)-1)])
dy = (directiony[random.randint(0,len(directiony)-1)])
cv.pack()
def p1up():
    # p1.y = -15
    cv.move(p1, 0, -15) # 0 is x parameter
def p1down():
    p1.y = 15
cv.bind_all('<KeyPress-w>', p1.y + 15) # Not <Key-Press-w>
while True:
    cv.move(ball, dx, dy)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.016666)
```

This will make the paddle *move*, but it still won't make the ball bounce.